# vue-server-renderer: window/document not defined in third packages

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using vue with ssr. (vue-server-renderer).

I get errors: `document not defined` / `window not defined` / `window.addEventLis… not defined`, when I try to use `renderToString` function.

Now I know window and document object doesn't not exist on the server side. so I use `no-ssr` package, that not render the components which have document and window inside.

But what about import statements? such as

```
 import muuri from 'muuri'; 
 // or
 import anime from 'animejs/lib/anime.es.js';
```

those packages doesn't have ssr compatibility. they access the dom indirect.

so when the render is run, it try to evaluate those library, and failed cause document/window not defined.

This step happends **before** the vue application is running. when webpack try to resolve the modules.

So what can I do about this?

Comment: Try to stub these packages for server build. You can't do anything if a package accesses `window` on import. As I can see, `animejs` doesn't do that.

Comment: Is there a package can stub document/window? not just set `document = {}` because those libs are try to access `document.createElement` and other properties on these object..

Comment: Do this with webpack config. Alias `muuri` to empty module. Something like that if you use CLI, https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-configure-vue-cli-3-to-leverage-webpack-root-folder-aliases/40943/2